# What are the semantics of adding the parameter in LHS of function definition in haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I'M a beginner in haskell and trying to understand the [Let vs Where wiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Let_vs._Where). At the end there's an example where adding the parameter `x` in the left hand side of function definition `fib` changes the semantics.

```
fib1 =
   let fib' 0 = 0
       fib' 1 = 1
       fib' n = fib1 (n - 1) + fib1 (n - 2)
   in  (map fib' [0 ..] !!)

fib2 x =
   let fib' 0 = 0
       fib' 1 = 1
       fib' n = fib2 (n - 1) + fib2 (n - 2)
   in  map fib' [0 ..] !! x
```

The wiki page states that "In the second case [`fib2`], fib' is redefined for every argument x". I'm looking for a beginner-friendly explanation of why this happens, and in general, are there more such hidden side effects?

The wiki page also has a link to an explanation about [eta reduction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_expansion), which states that an expression and its eta-reduction are equivalent. So, if `fib2` is the eta-abstraction of `fib1`, why aren't they equivalent?

Comment: Note: the first is **not** a function definition. It's a simple pattern binding. This changes the *type* when the `MonomorphismRestriction` is active (which is the default on most versions of Haskell.). So the first function will have a more monomorphic type than the latter.  To avoid this either specify the `NoMonomorphismRestriction` extension or provide an explicit type signature for the function.

Comment: Thanks, could you elaborate? Had I provided a type for `fib1`, it would have been a function?

Comment: @Bakuriu, it *is* a function definition, because it defines a function! But it's true that it's not *syntactically* a function definition, so the dreaded monomorphism restriction applies. Best by far, I think, for beginners to learn to *both* turn off the restriction *and* provide a signature for all top-level bindings. The monomorphism restriction is confusing, and not remotely worth the confusion.

Comment: There's also, IIRC, some differences with how they are treated at reduction (related to [supercombinators](https://wiki.haskell.org/Super_combinator)), but I know too little about that (or maybe that only applies to partial applications vs. lambdas?)

Comment: @dfeuer What is the difference between a syntactical definition and a regular definition?

Comment: What I mean is that the *form* of the definition does not indicate it is defining a function (it does not look like `f x ... = ...`, but it actually *does* define one.

Comment: Keep in mind that `f x = ...` is just syntactic sugar for `f = \x -> ...`. In some sense, a function definition is anything that assigns a value from a function type to a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last point is perhaps the most important one - `fib1` and `fib2` *are* indeed eta-equivalent, and the compiler is completely free to transform one into the other. Since this transformation has no effect on denotational semantics, only operational semantics, it is typically referred to as an optimization, if it "improves" the operational semantics of the program. The trouble is that it is hard to tell what "improves" really means.

The wiki page states

> The compiler cannot know whether you intended this -- while it
>   increases time complexity it may reduce space complexity.

This is true - in general, this "optimization" may not be an optimization, depending on how you measure performance. So, in general, the compiler will not perform this optimization, leaving the burden of doing so to the programmer if they so desire, unless it is *really* sure that it will indeed improve the performance of the code.

The difference is a characteristic called sharing. In `fib1`, the `fib'` calls in `map fib'` will be shared between the different calls of `fib1` inside the `fib'` function. This means that the entire list `map fib' [0..n]` must be retained for as long as the function is being computed. This could, in some cases, be bad for performance, but in this case it saves you *a lot* of recursive function calls. In `fib2`, each `map fib'` is computed separately, due to the fact that the parameter is outside the `let`. Consider this program, which is equivalent to `fib1` even without optimizations:

```
fib3 :: Int -> Integer 
fib3 =
   let fib' 0 = 0
       fib' 1 = 1
       fib' n = fib1 (n - 1) + fib1 (n - 2)
    in \x -> map fib' [0 ..] !! x
```

The placement of the `\x -> ..` is crucial - here it is `let fib' = .. in \x -> map fib' ..` but in `fib2` it is `\x -> let fib' = .. in map fib' ..`.

> Thus it will not float the definition out from under the binding of x.

This will obviously depend on the specific compiler you use and how you compile the program! I assume that this wiki page was written at a time when the compiler wasn't smart enough to figure out this particular example, but with GHC 7.10.3 and `-O2`, the compiler actually generates *identical* code for these two programs.

If you compile without optimizations, or interpret, the difference in performance will become apparent. It is not due to the monomorphism restriction - it is there even if you give monomorphic types to the functions:

```
fib1 :: Int -> Integer 
fib1 = ..

fib2 :: Int -> Integer 
fib2 x = ..
```

The difference is obvious:

```
>:set +s
>fib2 32
2178309
(10.86 secs, 6,063,137,456 bytes)
>fib1 32
2178309
(0.00 secs, 0 bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks, by "sharing" do you mean memoization?

Comment: I think the sentence "`fib1` and `fib2` are eta-equivalent" is _not_ correct. Eta-equivalence is _only_ between things of the form `\x -> e x` and `e`, that is, a lambda whose body is a function application. But `\x -> let decls in e x` has a lambda whose body is a let-binding, _not_ a function application. (And in any case I'm pretty sure eta equivalence isn't sound with respect to Haskell semantics.) I believe GHC calls this equivalence between lambdas and let bindings ["full laziness"](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/FAQ#When_can_I_rely_on_full_laziness.3F).

Comment: The compiler could eta expand fib3 and then beta reduce the lambda, which would give fib2 again.

Comment: Perhaps it should be "equivalent up to denotational semantics"? @Ingo Indeed, all three programs have the same denotational semantics - and hence a Haskell compiler is free to replace any one with any other. Their operational semantics may be different, but the operational semantics are really a function of compiler, optimization level, etc.